# Does awk print all if field variable doesn't exist?

Tags: awk

I am trying to understand some scripts that I have inherited and make use of awk.  In one of the scripts are these lines:

```
report=`<make call to Java class that generates a report`
report=`echo $report|awk '{print $5}'`
```

The report generated in line 1 has data like this:

```
ABC1234:0123456789:ABCDE
ABC4321:9876543210:EDCBA
...
```

The awk generated report is the same as the original one.

There is no 5th field in the report since there is no whitespace and a different field separator has not been defined.  I know that using $0 will return all fields.  Does specifying a field that doesn't exist do the same?

Comment: I figured it out.  The awk is not being performed on the report contents, but the results of the call to generate the report.  There are a number of system.out lines and the fifth one is the file name (including directory).  So, it grabs that argument and uses it further on in the script which simply copies it (hence the same contents).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No:

```
echo "1 2 3"|awk '{print $5}'
```

The above prints nothing. Don't know why it is behaving like you are specifying. If you were to use `"` instead of `'`, then it would print because $5 would be expanded by shell, but as written it should not.

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with your test.

The expected awk behavior in this case is to print a blank line for each input line, and that's what I see when I run with either the 1TA or gawk.